# HTML DOM: do carriage returns/tabs translate to spaces?

Tags: html, firebug, dom

Please take a look at this image:

[image]

On the top left, notice how `HelloWorld` does not have a space between them, while `Foo Bar` does. The right side shows the mark up; there is no space after `Foo` or before `Bar`; just a carriage return and a few tabs. The bottom left shows what the DOM is (per Firebug).

Question: what is there a space between `Foo` and `Bar`?

NOTE: here it is on JSFiddle, but it seems to have converted the tabs into spaces: http://jsfiddle.net/sM6rk/

**Original mark up (again, tabs turned into spaces):**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello<em>World</em></p>
        <p>Foo
            <em>Bar</em>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might help to see Chrome Inspector's representation of the DOM - http://i51.tinypic.com/106kcw5.png - in that you can see how the whitespace is still present in the document, and is then formatted as explained below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS spec explains the presentation of the [white-space processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model), specifically:

> 1. [..snip..]
> 2. [..snip..]
> 3. If 'white-space' is set to 'normal' or 'nowrap', linefeed characters are transformed for rendering purpose into one of the following characters: a space character, a zero width space character (U+200B), or no character (i.e., not rendered), according to UA-specific algorithms based on the content script.
> 4. If 'white-space' is set to 'normal', 'nowrap', or 'pre-line',
>      every tab (U+0009) is converted to a space (U+0020)
>      any space (U+0020) following another space (U+0020) — even a space before the inline, if that space also has 'white-space' set to 'normal', 'nowrap' or 'pre-line' — is removed.

Comment: My question is a mark up question, isn't it? Or is it also somehow a style sheet question?

Comment: If it's a markup question, then the answer is explained in my comment where Chrome shows that all of the white space in the source is still present in the DOM. If it's a question about why all that white space appears as a single space on screen, then it's a presentation question, which is answered by the CSS spec I quoted here :)

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, all whitespace is converted into a single space (or whatever equivalent for the language) unless it is within a block marked as `preserve-whitespace`. This includes spaces, tabs, and newlines.

For more specific details, please see [The HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.1).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all white space characters are interpreted as spaces, and multiple white space characters are interpreted as a single space.

So, the newline and spaces between Foo and Bar is interpreted as a single space.